# ScalaTest: QuickStart code fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/xml/NamespaceBinding

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I am just starting out with ScalaTest and following http://www.scalatest.org/quick_start page

I followed the steps as outlined (by downloading the jar file linked above the code)
and the code fails

```
 unittest vi ExampleSpec.scala
➜  unittest scalac -cp scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar ExampleSpec.scala
➜  unittest scala -cp scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar org.scalatest.run ExampleSpec
An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/xml/NamespaceBinding
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1368)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1033)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1011)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1509)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1011)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:827)
        at org.scalatest.run$.main(run.scala:120)
        at org.scalatest.run.main(run.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:105)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:40)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:130)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:105)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:130)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:34)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:70)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:91)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.xml.NamespaceBinding
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 29 more
```

My Scala Version is

```
➜  unittest scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.13.1 -- Copyright 2002-2019, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

I thought the error is because `scala-xml` is a separate project than Scala, so I downloaded the jar file from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-xml/2.11.0-M4

Next, I tried the entire process again and it fails with different error

```
 unittest scala -classpath "scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar:scala-xml-2.11.0-M4.jar" org.scalatest.run ExampleSpec
An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:515)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:417)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1368)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1033)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1011)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1509)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1011)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:827)
        at org.scalatest.run$.main(run.scala:120)
        at org.scalatest.run.main(run.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:105)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:40)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:130)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:105)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:130)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:34)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:70)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:91)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Serializable
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 39 more
```

Could someone please help me understand what the issue is?

Thank you

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

As per the comment from @J0HN and answer from @Mario, I was able to solve the issue

```
➜  unittest ll
total 17608
-rw-r--r--  1 harit  staff   504B Nov 21 17:15 ExampleSpec.scala
-rw-r--r--@ 1 harit  staff   555K Nov 22 10:35 scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 harit  staff   7.9M Nov 21 16:59 scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar
➜  unittest scalac -classpath "scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar:scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar" ExampleSpec.scala 
➜  unittest scala -classpath "scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar:scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar" org.scalatest.run ExampleSpec 
Run starting. Expected test count is: 2
ExampleSpec:
A Stack
- should pop values in last-in-first-out order
- should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
Run completed in 506 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 2
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.
➜  unittest
```

I have downloaded `scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar` from [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.13/1.2.0/) page

Comment: Could you post your build definition (i.e. pom.xml / build.sbt / etc.). Most likely there is a problem there. Chances are it has something to do with scala artifacts compiled against a certain version of scala, so `scala-xml` should actually be `scala-xml_2.13` (and you've downloaded `scala-xml_2.11`). But please post your build file, so it's less guessing on my side :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala [2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) decoupled `scala-xml` from the standard library:

> The following modules are no longer included in the distribution:
>   scala-xml, scala-parser-combinators, scala-swing. They are
>   community-maintained and published to Maven Central.

As suggested by J0HN, download [scala-xml_2.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.13/1.2.0) and try the following command

```
scala -cp scalatest-app_2.13-3.0.8.jar:scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar org.scalatest.run ExampleSpec
```